# What is an envelope line?

Tags: copywriting

We're putting together a physical direct mailer advertising leaflet.

I'm embarrassed to ask my colleague who asked me to include this request in addition to my headline.

Comment: Can you give us more context?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *envelope line* is almost certainly referring to one of two things:

**1.) An actual envelope line.**

If you're functioning as a designer of sorts, as I used to, then your colleague may be simply referring to the physical placement of elements on the envelope.

Perhaps what your colleague needs you to do is to move a design element because it interferes with the many folds, windows and/or postal service no-go zones that exist in the world of custom mailers.

I do not think this is likely, but it is possible.

**2.) A tagline.**

If you've ever received <strike>junkmail</strike> a direct mailer sent en masse, then you've seen taglines (or *envelope lines*, as the case may be). Examples might include:

> - You May Have Already Won **ONE MILLION DOLLARS!** (Check inside for details)
> - **CONGRATULATIONS!** You have prequalified for a new loan from **SMALLTOWN MOTORS**! (See inside for details)
> - **BIGCO INSURANCE** Could be saving you **HUNDREDS** on car insurance! (Details inside)

What your colleague is likely asking you for is a few small words that give the prospect a reason to open the envelope and not just dump it in the trash. And, IMHO, a good tagline is **5-7 words**, makes a **realistic promise** of a **tangible benefit** and requests the reader to **take action**. It's not easy to do all that in a few words but hey, that's why they pay you the big bucks, right?